# gulpでファイルのパスの指定方法

Tags: gulp

gulpで`.py`のファイルをすべて監視したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

```
gulp.watch([
    '*.py',
    '*/*.py'
], [
    'myTask',
]);
```

構成

- `test.py` <- 反応する
- hoge/

  - `test.py` <- 反応する
  - hoge/

    - `test.py` <- 反応しない・・・

このようになってしまいます。
どれだけ深いディレクトリであっても再帰的にファイルを見てくれるようにするにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*`はグロブスターと言いますが、リファレンスは[isaacs氏のREADME](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer)が参考になります。

問に対する答えは`['**/*.py']`です。
グロブのテストが出来るページがあるので、こちらで試してみてはいかがでしょうか？

> [Globtester - a little utility for testing minimatch](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJzT0tLX0iuoBAAFnwHF&r=eJy10M0OwiAMAOBXIZw00VVnVLYx3gVwf8m2EkAje3pZPGzRqzZpDz30a8tv3YPoXjpX0kF63VLBnZEjcT70VUk19mhzYhu1YemOHBmLJWPbgtQ4%2Br3rpiqPjSQ9zHG9pNkpO5tnQQW02FSJCRzmeYIrKzhETfD%2FklDfG7ly3%2BZPgI%2BtFw5MF3Blfl8INSIoaWNOy2fm1V5Utne8&)

Answer (score 1):

`*`は`/`を含みません。`**`は`/`も含みます。

```
gulp.watch(['**.py'],['mytask']);
```

参考にどうぞ: [minimatch（node.js で path match するライブラリ）のチートシートを作った - 詩と創作・思索のひろば](http://motemen.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/07/15/minimatch-cheat-sheet)